# Causal implication of identification

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Does the title "People in group A are more likely to be in Group B" suggest or imply any causality about being in group A being the reason they are in group B?  I understand that in a dictionary sense it does not, but I'm curious if causation is commonly read into such a statement.

Comment: It describes a correlation, and any causation can be read into it by the listener, depending on what they expect (plus intonation, facial expression, and other parts of the sentence that don't make it into spelling and punctuation). It is just as likely to be read as 'Being in Group B is the cause of being in Group A' as the reverse, since both are equally valid possibilities according to the data presented in the sentence.

Comment: One could be mischievous here and ask whether A and B are chosen randomly (from the set of all people-groups) or not.

Comment: This depends a lot on the context.  If I read that in a scientific or medical journal, I would expect the next sentence to explain whether there was any correlation or not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They certainly aren't, and that probably helped color my reading of the original text, but I can't ask the general question and the specific one without blurring how they are thought about.

Comment: @JohnFeltz it was a part of a reputable news headline so there isn't a lot of context to read in, though the bias of the news organization probably plays in some.

Comment: "Correlation does not imply causation."

Comment: I suppose a casual reader might jump to that conclusion.  There might be a characteristic C that is governing both A and B.

Answer (score 1):

> "People in Group A are more likely to be in Group B."

This means to me that there is some "overlap" between the "characteristics" that define the members of Group A and those that define the members of Group B -- a larger overlap than is the case for Groups C, D, E, etc. with Group B.

If you were to determine such a (statistical) relationship experimentally, you would call such a result a **correlation**, as noted by @JohnLawler.

A [**correlation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) may or may not imply a causal relationship between the characteristics that define Group A and those that define Group B.

Comment: correlation implying causation is a common misconception.